# Key usage with object lists in React

Tags: reactjs

I have the following react code to render `Event` objects:

```
<div>
    {events.map((event) => {
        return <Event key={event.id} event={event} onEdit={()=>{openEventEditor(event)}} />
    })}
</div>
```

A simplified `Event`objects looks like this:

```
{
    id:1,
    title: 'Lorem ipsum',
    description: 'This is the description',
    priority: 'HIGH'
}
```

The problem is if the user changes a property of the event (via the EventEditor) then the `Event` is not rerendered as the `id` property is unchanged.

How should I handle this?

Comment: So, inside `EventEditor`, when you change an event, you need to make sure that `events` is also changed (updated with new value). So, are you doing that?

Comment: Key does not prevent your component to rerender on property change, it just prevent rerender on list reorder, filter or if you insert an element at the beginning. Your issue is somewhere else

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It was my mistake. In one use case, I didn't update the `Event` object correctly. I used state derived from props and with an always regenerated random key, the root problem remained hidden.